# PowerBi - change parameter with key in url

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a website with various clients, and I read data into it through a script. Each client has a unique key.
I want Power BI to only be accessible through a link on the website. I've created a link that can transmit the unique key on the website, something like powerbi-dashboard/key.nl. I've written code that makes an API call to retrieve data from a web service, and this code includes a parameter containing the key.

I would like, when the link is clicked, for the key in the URL to be placed in the parameter so that the data is invoked.

Ideally, the key should not be visible in the URL to prevent it from being shared and only be accessible through the link on the site.

So the parameter should contain a part of the link
And ideally the part of the link is converted so the user doesnt see the api key that is used

---